# How to click svg using querySelector?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, onclick, click, jquery-selectors

I am trying to build a chrome extension to click an SVG on a webpage using the below command but it shows that "click" is not a function.

Can anyone give me some direction in order to solve this issue?

```js
document.querySelector("div[class^='SubmitChat__SubmitButton']").querySelector("svg > path(0)").click();
```

```html
<form class="SubmitChat__SubmitChatWrapper-kLTVjd ezNulO">

  <div id="PinToTop" style="display: none; border: groove; margin: 5px; padding: 5px;"></div>

  <div class="DefaultComments__DefaultCommentsWrapper-drohEF dbvkCO">

    <div class="SubmitChat__TextAreaWrapperBox-ijaLYA uQa-DJ">
      <textarea data-track-category="Interaction_Comment" data-track-action="click" data-track-name="field_comment" class="SubmitChat__TextAreaWrapper-cEDMAF joGtiU" style="height: 44px;"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="SubmitChat__SubmitButton-kXYuum kSQpDq">
      <span class="isvg loaded SubmitChat__SendMessageIcon-hzVurU lcJXRC">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
                    <path d="M25.305 16.07L7.503 24.307a.802.802 0 01-1.111-.925l1.923-7.493h0L6.392 8.396a.8.8 0 011.111-.925l17.802 8.236a.2.2 0 010 .363zm-16.638-.181h16" fill="none" stroke="#28232D" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="1.5">
                    </path>
                </svg>
            </span>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Basic debugging. Console.log everything. Also, are you sure the click event is assigned to the svg path? As opposed to the `<span>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really click an svg path but here is a solution:

```js
const pathElem = document.querySelector("div[class^='SubmitChat__SubmitButton'] svg > path")

pathElem.onclick = () => console.log("clicked")

pathElem.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"))
pathElem.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"))
```

```html
<form class="SubmitChat__SubmitChatWrapper-kLTVjd ezNulO">
    <div id="PinToTop" style="display: none; border: groove; margin: 5px; padding: 5px;"></div>
    <div class="DefaultComments__DefaultCommentsWrapper-drohEF dbvkCO">
        <div class="SubmitChat__TextAreaWrapperBox-ijaLYA uQa-DJ">
        <textarea data-track-category="Interaction_Comment" data-track-action="click" data-track-name="field_comment"  class="SubmitChat__TextAreaWrapper-cEDMAF joGtiU" style="height: 44px;"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="SubmitChat__SubmitButton-kXYuum kSQpDq">
            <span class="isvg loaded SubmitChat__SendMessageIcon-hzVurU lcJXRC">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
                    <path d="M25.305 16.07L7.503 24.307a.802.802 0 01-1.111-.925l1.923-7.493h0L6.392 8.396a.8.8 0 011.111-.925l17.802 8.236a.2.2 0 010 .363zm-16.638-.181h16" fill="none" stroke="#28232D" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="1.5">
                    </path>
                </svg>
            </span>
        </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Note that `.click()` works with HTML but not SVG elements. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

Also note that the click event handler in your case is probably not listening on the `path` element but rather on the `svg`, `div` or `span` tag.

Comment: I would add `bubbles: true` so the event propagates upwards.